# A minimum False Discovery Rate of 0.8 when doing multiple hypothesis testing on Logistic Regression Coefficient p-values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I currently have 8,000 predictor variables and a binary indicator response variable. I then did a logistic regression on each of the predictor variables, i.e., response regressed on predictor variable 1, response regressed on predictor variable 2, etc.

This gave me 8000 p-values associated with each predictor's estimated slope $\beta$ coefficient.

I then tried to control the FDR using Benjamini-Hochberg, but realized that unless I set my FDR to be 0.8, I could declare none of them significant. What is the interpretation of why this is so? Thanks.

Comment: The FDR is your rate of rejecting true null hypotheses given that some hypotheses may truly be false. You do not say *how* you are performing the Benjamini-Hochberg adjustment, but *if*, for example, *all* 8,000 null hypotheses were true, and then at least FDR$\times$8,000 of them should be rejected. It sounds to me like you are making a mistake in your adjustment process.

Comment: What is happening is that when I adjust for an FDR of $0.10$, I get no discoveries. The only time I start to get any discoveries is when I set the FDR to $0.8$. Does this indicate my assumptions are wrong?

Comment: As I said, I think it indicates that you're making a mistake in your calculations: the *minimum* number of false discoveries out of 8,000 with FDR=0.10 should be $0.1\times 8,000=800$. Your math is therefore off somewhere.

Comment: What I mean is that if I use the BH procedure, I have zero discoveries unless I set the FDR to be 0.8. That means I get zero discoveries associated with 0.5, 0.1, 0.2 all the way to until 0.8.

Comment: What I mean is that zero discoveries out of 8,000 tests with FDR = 0.10 implies that you did your math wrong.

Comment: FDR procedures control the expected FDR. However, if there are no discoveries (i.e., generate data so that all p-values are greater than 0.05), it appears to me that there will zero discoveries at an FDR. Are you defining it differently?

Comment: An expected FDR of 0.1 means that you would expect 10-percent truly false rejections out all true null hypotheses (maximum of 8,000 in your example). If all 8,000 null hypotheses are true then with the FDR would reject 800 of them (right? 800 false discoveries—i.e. 800 rejections of the null when the nulls are true). If less than 8,000 of your null hypotheses are true (e.g., 1,000 alternative hypotheses are true), then with FDR 0.1 you would expect to reject $7,000\times 0.1+1,000×(1−\beta)$. In either case you would expect to reject more than 0. Hence: you are doing the math wrong.